# What is the connection between the victims of the Unabomber?

Tags: plot-explanation, manhunt-unabomber

What is the possible connection among the victims of the Unabomber as presented in *Manhunt: Unabomber*? 
The series explains that he was picking up the names and addresses from who's who magazine.
Did Ted have any benefits by targeting those victims?

Comment: Worth noting, of course, that this isn't just a TV script with a made up story. The Unabomber actually existed as did his victims. He really did target those people and there was a warped and crazy reason in his mind for targeting them which made sense to him.

Comment: Well, I honestly dont know why its downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the possible connection among the victims of the Unabomber?

They all seem, in general, to fit into his ideas regarding the Industrial Revolution and it's effects on the world

He wrote a manifesto *Industrial Society and Its Future*

> [which] begins with Kaczynski's assertion: "The Industrial Revolution and its consequences have been a disaster for the human race."
>
> Kaczynski writes that technology has had a destabilizing effect on society, has made life unfulfilling, and has caused widespread psychological suffering. He argues that, because of technological advances, most people spend their time engaged in useless pursuits he calls "surrogate activities," wherein people strive toward artificial goals, including scientific work, consumption of entertainment, and following sports teams. He predicts that further technological advances will lead to extensive human genetic engineering and that human beings will be adjusted to meet the needs of the social systems, rather than vice versa. He believes that technological progress can be stopped, unlike some people, who he says understand some of its negative effects yet passively accept it as inevitable, and calls for a return to "wild nature."
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski#Summary)</sup>

The list of [**victims/targets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski#Bombings) is also on Wikipedia who, as I stated, generally fit into his view as contributing to the effects he has issues with.

Of course, Kaczynski's actual methodology for chosing targets is somewht haphazard and highly inflused by "non-logical" thinking.